# chmod: Operation not permitted

Tags: command-line, permissions, root, chmod

how can change my folder permissions?
I also tried it as root but it did not work
and I also cannot change the ownership.

```
root@darkmark:~# pwd
/root
root@darkmark:~# sudo chown -R darkmark '/home/darkmark/hs'
chown: changing ownership of '/home/darkmark/hs': Operation not permitted
root@darkmark:~# sudo chmod 755 '/home/darkmark/hs'
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/darkmark/hs': Operation not permitted
root@darkmark:~# _

darkmark@darkmark:~$ ls -l
total 32
drwxrwxr-x 4 darkmark darkmark 4096 Jul 12 15:39 dictionaries
drwxrwxr-x 3 darkmark darkmark 4096 Jul 12 21:27 Directory-Wordlist
drwxrwxrwx 2 darkmark darkmark 4096 Jul 14 20:35 Downloads
drwxrwxrwx 3 root     root     4096 Jul 10 16:55 hs
drwxrwxr-x 5 darkmark darkmark 4096 Jul 10 15:32 Main_data_dir
drwxrwxr-x 6 darkmark darkmark 4096 Jul 12 19:46 SecLists
drwxrwxr-x 3 darkmark darkmark 4096 Jul 14 20:35 wifite
drwxrwxr-x 3 darkmark darkmark 4096 Jul 14 20:57 wordlist
darkmark@darkmark:~$ sudo chmod -rw hs
[sudo] password for darkmark:
chmod: changing permissions of 'hs': Operation not permitted
darkmark@darkmark:~$ _
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1156997) your question and use copy and paste from the text in your terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dir probably has the immutable attribute set. Try

```
# chattr -R -ia hs
```

Also, use the search function before posting.

Comment: thank you bro help it work thank you bro really

Comment: You're welcome! Please hit the accept button if my answer solved your problem :)